# How can I code a Xamarin.Forms splash screen with a left right swipe?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I have seen some applications that start up with a splash screen with a next button that when click makes another page roll in from the right. On those pages is usually a next or back button that lets a user go back to the first screen or proceed to the next.

I've not seen anything in the Xamarin examples on how to do this.

Would appreciate if someone could provide an example or give me some suggestions as to how I can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is CarouselView. It doesn't come bundled with the stable Xamarin.Forms installation so you'll have to download it separately or add through NuGet.

Here's the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView) and the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView).

With the CarouselView, you can have multiple "pages" in the style of splash screen/onboarding screens that are popular these days.

Here's an article on how to use the control: https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

---

**Edit:** On another thought, I'd probably use the [CarouselView implementation by GitHub user alexrainman](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView). It has more features, is better tested and more mature.